# Entity Print PDF Layout for Views page

Tags: theming, 8

My requirement is to convert a views page into a PDF. I have created the views page with table formatting and a PDF plugin attached to the header that allows one to download the views page as PDF. I created an entity-print.html twig template and an HTML structure copied from the answer in this post [How to customize entity print pdf](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282282/how-to-customize-entity-print-pdf) and created a twig variable 'footer' in THEME_preprocess_page function in the theme's .theme file but the calls {{ footer }} to that variable in the template returns nothing.

In other to at least test CSS formatting, I placed these in the respective files:

ENTITY-PRINT.HTML.TWIG

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {{ entity_print_css }}
</head>
<body>
{# The footer is repeated on all pages and must be printed first. #}

<footer>
    {{  footer  }}
</footer>
{%  if cover_page  %}
<div class="cover-page">
    {{ cover_page }}
</div>
{%  endif  %}
{# The header is repeated after the cover page for all pages. #}
<header>
    {{  header  }}
</header>
<div class="page">
    {{ content }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

THEMENAME.THEME

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['footer'] = "HERE IS YOUR FOOTER";
  $variables['header'] = "HERE IS YOUR HEADER";
}
```

IN .INFO.YML

```
entity_print:
 views:
   views_page_machine_name: 'theme_name/result-pdf'
```

IN .LIBRARIES.YML

```
result-pdf:
  css:
    theme:
      styles/result-pdf.css: {}
```

IN CSS FILE (i.e. result-pdf.css)

```
* {
    color: red;
}

div {
    background: blue;
}
```

and then created result-pdf.css but the styles did not change anything in the generated pdf.

One of the answers in another post [Entity print get variable in twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244817/entity-print-get-variable-in-twig-template?answertab=votes#tab-top) pointed to creating an entity specific template for layout of the PDF  with HTML as required. For example, for the article content type you have node--article--pdf.html.twig. What is the template suggestion for a views as described in my case?

The question is how do I achieve:

1. create a HTML layout format that is fed all the fields from the views page
2. rightly set the footer/header variable for output in the entity-print.html template mentioned above
3. turn bullet into A pdf (so that the download link on the views page generates the formatted html as pdf).

Perhaps bullet 1-3 is irrelevant, a step by step direction on how to have a views page formatted as required and converted to PDF using the entity print module will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you see when you add `{{ kint(footer) }}` to your template?

Comment: @Beau Without it the download link works but with it and clearing cache I got this error "
Error message
Error generating document: Failed to generate PDF: 'box_sizing' is not a recognized CSS property., 'overflow_x' is not a recognized.., '.kint ul:not(.kint-tabs) li' is not valid, The CSS selector '.kint ul:not(.kint-tabs) li>dl' is not valid, The CSS selector '.kint ul.kint-tabs li:not(.kint-active-tab)' is not valid, The CSS selector '.kint>dl:not(.kint-trace)>dd>ul.kint-tabs li' is not valid, The CSS selector '.kint>dl:not(.kint-trace)>dd>ul.kint-tabs li.kint-active-tab' is not valid
"

Comment: I suppose I should have also asked - do you have the `kint` sub-module enabled? if not, please be sure to download devel and then enable `kint`. Here is a tutorial: https://www.webwash.net/how-to-print-variables-using-kint-in-drupal-8/

Comment: I've got devel installed with kint enabled already. Maybe the issue is what template to place it in. I'm placing it it in entity-print.html.twig and added the kint call `{{ kint() }}` and then `{{ kint(footer) }}`, so now when I tried to download the pdf it took a while and then `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`

Comment: `kint()` is a pretty resource-heavy function. Try eliminating the `{{ kint() }}` call. If you continue to receive memory exhaust errors, then try `{{ kint(footer|keys) }}` in place of `{{ kint(footer) }}`. Also, use `{{ kint(_context|keys) }}` to verify what top level keys are actually available to you. If you don't see a `footer` key, then it seems your preprocess and your twig aren't talking.

Comment: So after removing the knit function call I now see this at the bottom of the views page `footer string(19) "HERE IS YOUR FOOTER"` but nothing on the footer of the pdf generated. I have the variable set in the function THEMENAME_preprocess_page

Comment: Sounds like you're getting closer. I recommend editing your question to include your template and preprocess code. Otherwise, we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question asap.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `THEME_preprocess_entity_print()`? You should generally use the preprocess hook that matches the template name.

Comment: Thanks @Beau for pointing this direction. THEME_preprocess_entity_print() worked as the footer is attached to the header section. So I had to rearrange the template, repositioning the <footer> after the main content and placing the header before. Two problem remain, the css set in info.yml and libraries.yml is not affecting the display. I've included the css style I have in the css file.] in the question.

Comment: A better practice is to define your own library entries in a THEME_NAME.libraries.yml and attach those libraries to your templates. See this change record for info on attaching a library to your template: https://www.drupal.org/node/2456753

Comment: Oh I see. I followed the usage documentation https://www.drupal.org/node/2706755. I'll try out your recommendation.

Comment: `{{ attach_library('THEME/result-pdf') }}` works when applied to any other type of template (i.e. page, node, etc) but doesn't work when place in `entity-print.html.twig` as the styles affecting the page template doesn't affect the PF generated. So seems entity_print is set to only work with the `{{ entity_print_css }}` variable and not by library attachment. If I remove the the variable and place only the library attachment no style is applied, not even the global css style but the global style is applied when the `entity_print_css` variable is present.

Answer (score 1):

The solution came down to replacing "views" with "view" - without the s and "views_page_machine_name" with "all", such that this:

```
entity_print:
 views:
   views_page_machine_name : 'theme_name/result-pdf'
```

became:

```
entity_print:
 view:
   all: 'theme_name/result-pdf'
```